# Помогите разобраться с скриптом jquery функции

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, html-select

У меня есть такой HTML, он загружается на сайте в эту контент

```
<div id="ad-car-detail-content">
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://avtousta.ucoz.com/js/board/add-cars-board.js"></script>
```

функция такая.
при выборе **select** тег загружается  нужный марка или модель автомобиля.
Это обычный скрипт написанный мной, работает отлично нужного марку и модель загружается как надо.
Но тут есть одно проблема который при выборе марку **select**
на этом **INPUT** должен меняться **ID** и **VALUE**

```
<input class="catSelector9" checked="checked" type="button" value="2" name="ocat" id="cus2">
```

А при выборе модель на этом **INPUT** должен меняться **VALUE**
от **OPTION** *текст*

пример вот так.
Есть такой тег

```
<select id="car_model_id"><option value="0">A7</option></select>
<input value="0" type="button" id="bdF1" name="title">
```

При выборе **option**
Получилось так

```
<select id="car_model_id"><option value="0">A7</option></select>
<input value="A7" type="button" id="bdF1" name="title">
```

На этом сайте мне помогли  такой скрипт на обоих функции

```
<script>$("select.car_Marka").on("change", function() {var selected_option = $("select.car_Marka option:selected");$("input.catSelector9").attr("id", selected_option.attr("id")).attr("value", selected_option.attr("value"));});</script>
```

и здесь нашел такой скрипт переделал

```
<script>$("select#car_model_id").change(function () {var str = "";$("select#car_model_id option:selected").each(function() {str += $( this ).text() + " ";});$("input#bdF1").val( str );}).change();</script>
```

На компьютере создаю **test html** сохраняю это скрипты 
и 
это код

```html
<div class="manTable" id="bdM64"><div id="bdM49"><div class="manTd2" id="bdM51"><select id="bdF18" class="manFlFlt1" name="filter1" onchange="fillMark();"><option id="bdM50" value="0">Avtomobil: Tipi</option><option value="1">Minik avtomobilləri</option><option value="2">Minik avtomobilləri kommersiya</option><option value="3">Yük Avtomobilləri</option><option value="4">Avtobuslar</option><option value="5">Qoşqu dartanlar</option><option value="6">Qoşqular</option><option value="7">Çıxarıla bilinən kuzalar</option><option value="8">Motoskletlər</option><option value="9">Baggilər</option><option value="10">Skuterlər</option><option value="11">Moto yolsuzluq</option><option value="12">Karting</option><option value="13">Yolsuzluq moto amfibi</option><option value="14">Yolsuzluq Qar üçün</option></select></div></div><div id="bdM61"><div class="manTd2" id="bdM63"><input class="catSelector9" checked="checked" type="button" value="2" name="ocat" id="cus2"><div id="car_mark"><select class="car_Marka" id="car_Marka" onchange="fillModel();"><option id="0" value="0">Marka: Seçin</option><option value="90001" id="cus90001">AC</option><option value="90002" id="cus90002">Acura</option><option value="90003" id="cus90003">Adler</option><option value="90004" id="cus90004">Alfa Romeo</option><option value="90005" id="cus90005">Alpina</option><option value="90006" id="cus90006">Alpine</option><option value="90007" id="cus90007">AM General</option><option value="90008" id="cus90008">AMC</option><option value="90009" id="cus90009">Ariel</option><option value="90010" id="cus90010">Aro</option><option value="90011" id="cus90011">Asia</option><option value="90012" id="cus90012">Aston Martin</option><option value="90013" id="cus90013">Audi</option><option value="90014" id="cus90014">Austin</option><option value="90015" id="cus90015">Autobianchi</option><option value="90016" id="cus90016">Baltijas Dzips</option><option value="90017" id="cus90017">Beijing</option><option value="90018" id="cus90018">Bentley</option><option value="90019" id="cus90019">Bertone</option><option value="90020" id="cus90020">Bitter</option><option value="90021" id="cus90021">BMW</option><option value="90022" id="cus90022">Borgward</option><option value="90023" id="cus90023">Brabus</option><option value="90024" id="cus90024">Brilliance</option><option value="90025" id="cus90025">Bristol</option><option value="90026" id="cus90026">Bufori</option><option value="90027" id="cus90027">Bugatti</option><option value="90028" id="cus90028">Buick</option><option value="90029" id="cus90029">BYD</option><option value="90030" id="cus90030">Byvin</option><option value="90031" id="cus90031">Cadillac</option><option value="90032" id="cus90032">Callaway</option><option value="90033" id="cus90033">Carbodies</option><option value="90034" id="cus90034">Caterham</option><option value="90035" id="cus90035">Changan</option><option value="90036" id="cus90036">ChangFeng</option><option value="90037" id="cus90037">Chery</option><option value="90038" id="cus90038">Chevrolet</option><option value="90039" id="cus90039">Chrysler</option><option value="90040" id="cus90040">Citroen</option><option value="90041" id="cus90041">Cizeta</option><option value="90042" id="cus90042">Coggiola</option><option value="90043" id="cus90043">Dacia</option><option value="90044" id="cus90044">Dadi</option><option value="90045" id="cus90045">Daewoo</option><option value="90046" id="cus90046">DAF</option><option value="90047" id="cus90047">Daihatsu</option><option value="90048" id="cus90048">Daimler</option><option value="90049" id="cus90049">Datsun</option><option value="90050" id="cus90050">De Tomaso</option><option value="90051" id="cus90051">DeLorean</option><option value="90052" id="cus90052">Derways</option><option value="90053" id="cus90053">DeSoto</option><option value="90054" id="cus90054">Dodge</option><option value="90055" id="cus90055">DongFeng</option><option value="90056" id="cus90056">Doninvest</option><option value="90057" id="cus90057">Donkervoort</option><option value="90058" id="cus90058">DS</option><option value="90059" id="cus90059">E-Car</option><option value="90060" id="cus90060">Eagle</option><option value="90061" id="cus90061">Eagle Cars</option><option value="90062" id="cus90062">Ecomotors</option><option value="90063" id="cus90063">FAW</option><option value="90064" id="cus90064">Ferrari</option><option value="90065" id="cus90065">Fiat</option><option value="90066" id="cus90066">Fisker</option><option value="90067" id="cus90067">Ford</option><option value="90068" id="cus90068">Foton</option><option value="90069" id="cus90069">FSO</option><option value="90070" id="cus90070">Fuqi</option><option value="90071" id="cus90071">Geely</option><option value="90072" id="cus90072">Geo</option><option value="90073" id="cus90073">GMC</option><option value="90074" id="cus90074">Gonow</option><option value="90075" id="cus90075">Gordon</option><option value="90076" id="cus90076">Great Wall</option><option value="90077" id="cus90077">Hafei</option><option value="90078" id="cus90078">Haima</option><option value="90079" id="cus90079">Haval</option><option value="90080" id="cus90080">Hawtai</option><option value="90081" id="cus90081">Hindustan</option><option value="90082" id="cus90082">Holden</option><option value="90083" id="cus90083">Honda</option><option value="90084" id="cus90084">HuangHai</option><option value="90085" id="cus90085">Hummer</option><option value="90086" id="cus90086">Hyundai</option><option value="90087" id="cus90087">Infiniti</option><option value="90088" id="cus90088">Innocenti</option><option value="90089" id="cus90089">Invicta</option><option value="90090" id="cus90090">Iran Khodro</option><option value="90091" id="cus90091">Isdera</option><option value="90092" id="cus90092">Isuzu</option><option value="90093" id="cus90093">IVECO</option><option value="90094" id="cus90094">JAC</option><option value="90095" id="cus90095">Jaguar</option><option value="90096" id="cus90096">Jeep</option><option value="90097" id="cus90097">Jensen</option><option value="90098" id="cus90098">JMC</option><option value="90099" id="cus90099">Kia</option><option value="90100" id="cus90100">Koenigsegg</option><option value="90101" id="cus90101">KTM</option><option value="90102" id="cus90102">Lamborghini</option><option value="90103" id="cus90103">Lancia</option><option value="90104" id="cus90104">Land Rover</option><option value="90105" id="cus90105">Landwind</option><option value="90106" id="cus90106">Lexus</option><option value="90107" id="cus90107">Liebao Motor</option><option value="90108" id="cus90108">Lifan</option><option value="90109" id="cus90109">Lincoln</option><option value="90110" id="cus90110">Lotus</option><option value="90111" id="cus90111">LTI</option><option value="90112" id="cus90112">Luxgen</option><option value="90113" id="cus90113">Mahindra</option><option value="90114" id="cus90114">Marcos</option><option value="90115" id="cus90115">Marlin</option><option value="90116" id="cus90116">Marussia</option><option value="90117" id="cus90117">Maruti</option><option value="90118" id="cus90118">Maserati</option><option value="90119" id="cus90119">Maybach</option><option value="90120" id="cus90120">Mazda</option><option value="90121" id="cus90121">McLaren</option><option value="90122" id="cus90122">Mega</option><option value="90123" id="cus90123">Mercedes-Benz</option><option value="90124" id="cus90124">Mercury</option><option value="90125" id="cus90125">Metrocab</option><option value="90126" id="cus90126">MG</option><option value="90127" id="cus90127">Microcar</option><option value="90128" id="cus90128">Minelli</option><option value="90129" id="cus90129">MINI</option><option value="90130" id="cus90130">Mitsubishi</option><option value="90131" id="cus90131">Mitsuoka</option><option value="90132" id="cus90132">Morgan</option><option value="90133" id="cus90133">Morris</option><option value="90134" id="cus90134">Nissan</option><option value="90135" id="cus90135">Noble</option><option value="90136" id="cus90136">Oldsmobile</option><option value="90137" id="cus90137">Opel</option><option value="90138" id="cus90138">Osca</option><option value="90139" id="cus90139">Packard</option><option value="90140" id="cus90140">Pagani</option><option value="90141" id="cus90141">Panoz</option><option value="90142" id="cus90142">Perodua</option><option value="90143" id="cus90143">Peugeot</option><option value="90144" id="cus90144">PGO</option><option value="90145" id="cus90145">Piaggio</option><option value="90146" id="cus90146">Plymouth</option><option value="90147" id="cus90147">Pontiac</option><option value="90148" id="cus90148">Porsche</option><option value="90149" id="cus90149">Premier</option><option value="90150" id="cus90150">Proton</option><option value="90151" id="cus90151">PUCH</option><option value="90152" id="cus90152">Puma</option><option value="90153" id="cus90153">Qoros</option><option value="90154" id="cus90154">Qvale</option><option value="90155" id="cus90155">Ravon</option><option value="90156" id="cus90156">Reliant</option><option value="90157" id="cus90157">Renaissance</option><option value="90158" id="cus90158">Renault</option><option value="90160" id="cus90160">Rezvani</option><option value="90161" id="cus90161">Rimac</option><option value="90162" id="cus90162">Rolls-Royce</option><option value="90163" id="cus90163">Ronart</option><option value="90164" id="cus90164">Rover</option><option value="90165" id="cus90165">Saab</option><option value="90166" id="cus90166">Saleen</option><option value="90167" id="cus90167">Santana</option><option value="90168" id="cus90168">Saturn</option><option value="90169" id="cus90169">Renault Samsung</option><option value="90170" id="cus90170">SEAT</option><option value="90171" id="cus90171">ShuangHuan</option><option value="90172" id="cus90172">Skoda</option><option value="90173" id="cus90173">Smart</option><option value="90174" id="cus90174">Soueast</option><option value="90175" id="cus90175">Spectre</option><option value="90176" id="cus90176">Spyker</option><option value="90177" id="cus90177">SsangYong</option><option value="90178" id="cus90178">Subaru</option><option value="90179" id="cus90179">Suzuki</option><option value="90180" id="cus90180">Talbot</option><option value="90181" id="cus90181">TATA</option><option value="90182" id="cus90182">Tatra</option><option value="90183" id="cus90183">Tazzari</option><option value="90184" id="cus90184">Tesla</option><option value="90185" id="cus90185">Tianma</option><option value="90186" id="cus90186">Tianye</option><option value="90187" id="cus90187">Tofas</option><option value="90188" id="cus90188">Toyota</option><option value="90189" id="cus90189">Trabant</option><option value="90190" id="cus90190">Tramontana</option><option value="90191" id="cus90191">Triumph</option><option value="90192" id="cus90192">TVR</option><option value="90193" id="cus90193">Ultima</option><option value="90194" id="cus90194">Vauxhall</option><option value="90195" id="cus90195">Vector</option><option value="90196" id="cus90196">Venturi</option><option value="90197" id="cus90197">Volkswagen</option><option value="90198" id="cus90198">Volvo</option><option value="90199" id="cus90199">Vortex</option><option value="90200" id="cus90200">W Motors</option><option value="90201" id="cus90201">Wartburg</option><option value="90202" id="cus90202">Westfield</option><option value="90203" id="cus90203">Wiesmann</option><option value="90204" id="cus90204">Willys</option><option value="90205" id="cus90205">Xin Kai</option><option value="90206" id="cus90206">Zastava</option><option value="90207" id="cus90207">Zenos</option><option value="90208" id="cus90208">Zenvo</option><option value="90209" id="cus90209">Zotye</option><option value="90210" id="cus90210">ZX</option><option value="90211" id="cus90211">Avtokam</option><option value="90212" id="cus90212">Astro</option><option value="90213" id="cus90213">Bronto</option><option value="90214" id="cus90214">VAZ (Lada)</option><option value="90215" id="cus90215">QAZ</option><option value="90216" id="cus90216">YO-Mobil</option><option value="90217" id="cus90217">ZAZ</option><option value="90218" id="cus90218">ZİL</option><option value="90219" id="cus90219">ZİS</option><option value="90220" id="cus90220">İJ</option><option value="90221" id="cus90221">KaMaz</option><option value="90222" id="cus90222">Kanonir</option><option value="90223" id="cus90223">Kombat</option><option value="90224" id="cus90224">LuAZ</option><option value="90225" id="cus90225">Moskviç</option><option value="90226" id="cus90226">SeAZ</option><option value="90227" id="cus90227">SMZ</option><option value="90228" id="cus90228">TaqAZ</option><option value="90229" id="cus90229">UAZ</option><option value="90230" id="cus90230">Eksklyuziv</option></select></div><script>$("select.car_Marka").on("change", function() {var selected_option = $("select.car_Marka option:selected");$("input.catSelector9").attr("id", selected_option.attr("id")).attr("value", selected_option.attr("value"));});</script></div></div><div id="bdM5"><div id="car_model"><select id="car_model_id"><option value="0">Model: Seçin</option><option value="10001">378 GT Zagato</option><option value="10002">ACE</option><option value="10003">Aceca</option><option value="10004">Cobra</option><option value="10001">378 GT Zagato</option><option value="10002">ACE</option><option value="10003">Aceca</option><option value="10004">Cobra</option></select></div><input value="0" type="button" id="bdF1" name="title"><script>$("select#car_model_id").change(function () {var str = "";$("select#car_model_id option:selected").each(function() {str += $( this ).text() + " ";});$("input#bdF1").val( str );}).change();</script></div><div id="bdM65"><div class="manTdBut" id="bdM66"><input type="submit" style="display:none;" id="doSmbBt"><input type="button" class="manFlSbm" id="bdF77" style="font-weight:bold;" value="Добавить" onclick="document.getElementById('doSmbBt').click();"><input class="manFlRst" type="reset" id="bdF23" value="Очистить" onclick=""></div></div><input type="hidden" name="a" value="12"><input type="hidden" name="ssid" value="Yats5PDJ"><input type="hidden" id="numi" value="1"></div>
```

работает отлично.
но функционально работы группы **SELECT**
на сайт должен загружаться вот так

```
<div id="ad-car-detail-content">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://avtousta.ucoz.com/js/board/add-cars-board.js"></script>
```

в таком случай не хочет работать функции **JQUEY ONCHANGE.VAL**

Помогите пожалуйста! 
В чем проблема что ему не дает работать?
на сайте используется **jquery 7.1.2**

Comment: несколько сумбурно , не могли бы вы тезисно описать цели , задачи и выложить в том виде что у Вас на https://jsfiddle.net/ .

Comment: @redroid чтоб шаг за шагом объяснить. а то кто знает что происходить

Comment: @redroid вы лучший бы помогли меня

Comment: Если я верно понял из того, что вы описали. То проблема в том, что вы вешаете обработчик на select до того, как он появился на странице. Поэтому событие change не срабатывает. Повешайте обработчик после того, как добавите select в DOM. Или делегируйте событие на документ.

Comment: @PavelGorobtsov  вот именно так, *не работает обработчик на select до того, как он появился на странице* а эту то что вы написали я не понял **Повешайте обработчик после того, как добавите select в DOM. Или делегируйте событие на документ**

Comment: @PavelGorobtsov помогите по подробнее пожалуйста!

Comment: @PavelGorobtsov а как ?

Comment: @PavelGorobtsov вы имеете введу что при загрузке скрипта какой то функция опаздывает или как? на данный момент функции работает с помощью класс а ранее он был по ИД когда было по ИД все работала потом здесь мне помог **DmitryScaletta** чтоб функции работали через jquery по класс. спасибо ему скрипт работает по класс отлично, но только в тестовом режиме на компьютере при загрузке на страницу не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас плохое описание вопроса, поэтому трудно вам помочь.

Предположительно есть 2 проблемы:

1. Обработчик на событие change добавляется раньше, чем элемент появляется в DOM.
   Возможные решение:

   - Делегирование события
   - Добавить обработчик после того, как элемент появится на странице
2. Вторая проблема: событие change на селекте не срабатываем, если в нем всего один элемент (и это верно, т.к. изменения значения не происходит).
   Возможные решение:

   - Добавить еще один option (например "Выберите пункт"), если изменения необходимо произвести только после взаимодействия с контролом.
   - Вызвать событие в ручном режиме

[Вот пример  в jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2942887/)

index.html

```
<div id="ad-car-detail-content"></div>
<input type="text" id="result">
```

js

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init () {
    // Делегируем событие
  $(document).on('change', 'select#car_model_id', onInputChanged);

    // Добавляем селект
    var select = '<select id="car_model_id" value="-1"><option value="0">A7</option></select>'
    $('#ad-car-detail-content').html(select);

  // Т.к. options всего один - то change не произойдет (value не меняется)
  // Тригерим руками
  $('select#car_model_id').trigger('change')
}

function onInputChanged(e) {
    console.log('change', e);

  $('#result').val(e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответь. но такой код мне не помогает. Если не понятно! токгда по подробнее. вот есть такой код на сайте `<div id="ad-car-detail-content">
 </div>` сюда загружаются с помощью этого скрипта `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://avtousta.ucoz.com/js/board/add-cars-board.js"></script>`
 вес **селекты оптионс и скрипты для функции изменения value input и id** как видно загруженный контент через сайт не работает. а если создам на компьютере тест html и сохраню скрипт функции и select options без вызова загрузки через  скрипт тогда работает

Comment: Не уверен, что комментарий к обработанной тревоге обработался правильно, поэтому продублирую здесь. Удаление вопросов уместно только для совершенно неспасаемых – вроде спама. В данном случае стоит использовать тревогу «закрыть» — «необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса»